# JSF 2 Property does not reflect the changes after an ajax action

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

This is the situation:

I have a popup box to select one of the item listed(click the showParentAssetSearchButton) . Once selected the value of the selected item will be display in the main screen. In the main screen, there will be a button to clear up the item that selected. It will trigger an ajax action to the managed bean to clear the binding value(via click clearParentAssetButton).

When i do debugging, the value is clear and will not show in the main screen. However when i click on the save button, i notice that the property that should be empty is not actually empty. It still keep the value.

Following is the snippet UI code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="myregion">
    <p:inputText id="parentAsset" 
                 ondblclick="parentAssetDlg.show()"
                 value="#{assetMasterCreatePage.parentAsset.shortName}"
                 rendered="#{not empty assetMasterCreatePage.parentAsset}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" 
                 id="showParentAssetSearchButton" 
                 type="button"
                 title="#{msg.label_asset_search_parent_asset}"
                 onclick="parentAssetDlg.show()" />
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" 
                 id="clearParentAssetButton" 
                 title="#{msg.label_asset_clear_parent_asset}"
                 actionListener="#{assetMasterCreatePage.doResetParentAsset}"
                 immediate="true"
                 process="@form"
                 update="clearParentAssetButton, myregion"
                 disabled="#{empty assetMasterCreatePage.parentAsset}" />
 ........
 <p:commandButton value="#{msg.button_save}" icon="ui-icon-disk" 
                  action="#{assetMasterCreatePage.doSaveAsset}" />
```

This is the managed bean snippet

```
@ManagedBean(name="assetMasterCreatePage")
@ViewScoped
public class AssetMasterCreatePage extends DefaultAssetMasterPage {
      private AssetMaster assetMaster;
      private AssetMaster parentAsset;

..........
.........
  public void doResetParentAsset(){
     parentAsset = null;
  }
  public String doSaveAssetMaster(){
    assetMaster.setParentAsset(parentAsset);
    assetMasterService.save(assetMaster);
    MessageUtils.saveSuccessMessage();
    return "save";
  }

}
```

As you can see, when the button of the clearParentAssetButton is click, it will trigger ajax action #{assetMasterCreatePage.doResetParentAsset} to reset the value of the parentAsset. The issue here is when saving, the parentAsset which already should be null is not null.

I am using JSF 2 to perform the tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Strange, is there any other fields which hold the value of `parentAsset`, I mean's in the page, have some fields like
`<h:inputText value="parentAsset.shortName"/>`, when you click the save button, a new `parentAsset` is initialized and saved, and also you can debug it and see the `parentAsset`'s hash code to make sure whether the same one.